# How to add button for "Send Transcript" to Directline WebChat

Tags: botframework

I would like customers to be able to click a button to send themselves a transcript at any point in the conversation. This button should essentially send a message to the bot which would initiate an “email transcript" dialog to prompt for their email and send the transcript. I was able to add a button to the directline webchat client (in my title bar) but I can't figure out how to have it create an activity for the bot. I have a custom store that sends an "inactive" activity but I wasn't able to use this same method to make the button send an activity. Can this be achieved? Or is there another way for customers to get a copy of their transcript?

I have achieved the actual transcript retrieval and emailing in code, initiates by a LUIS intent, I just want to provide an intuitive "always there" option to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebChat offers a simple sample that shows you [how to send activities programmatically to the bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/d.post-activity-event#overview). In this sample they are creating a separate button with an Event Listener, which will sent your message as a message activity.

If you would like to sent it as an event in the background, you could have a look at [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event), which you could combine with the event listener of the first example.

- [How to send a message programmatically](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/d.post-activity-event)
- [How to send welcome event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event)

> **Note:** you need to use the [JavaScript WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#integrate-with-javascript), it is not possible to add this functionality to the iFrame version of the Bot Service.

Comment: Perfect, the first link is exactly what I was looking for. As I am collecting the email address via dialog it is appropriate to send as message activity. I didn't think to look in the API folder to find this sample. Thanks for your help!